# Gzipping HTML files doesn't make them load faster

Tags: html, performance, amazon-s3, iframe, gzip

I'm trying to build an HTML file that contains a bunch of plotly charts stored in iframes. Each plotly chart is itself an html document, stored in AWS S3 and loaded using the src attribute of the iframe. My objective is now to make the loading of that main HTML file faster.

I read on other posts that enabling GZIP compression would make that happen, so I set my AWS S3 bucket up accordingly, gzipped my individual HTML plots (which divided their size by ~3) and sent them over to S3, replacing the unzipped plots.

I then tried to load my main page again. The page loaded correctly, which means that the unzipping worked, but the time it took to load was around the same as before compression (Google's [speed test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) confirms that, and gave the exact same score as before, with similar results on the metrics). I am surprised by this, as I thought that gzipping would at least have some impact on loading time, but it seems to have none whatsoever. Could anyone point me out to anything I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it just means that the sizes you are dealing with are not so large that compressing anything saves enough time to be of any benefit.  Also, decompressing takes a little time.  If that time is longer than the savings due to transmitting a little less data, then you even wait a little longer for the complete procedure.  You will feel the benefit much stronger if your servers are very slow; but S3 is not known to be slow ;-)  In this case you would need to save a lot by reducing your data before you can measure it.

Also, your data could be of a kind which does not benefit at all from gzip compression, e.g. because it already is compressed.  I assume with »plots« you mean images, and images typically are stored as JPGs or PNGs which both are already compressed formats (and which both are optimized for image data, so they are way better suited to the task than gzip).

Gzip is a general purpose compression which is based on the notion that raw data often contains repetition, redundancies, and often uses a reduced subset of the available alphabet.  E.g. text files might only use the ASCII subset and within this often just letters, numbers and some punctuation characters.  But the available alphabet would have been the complete value range 0..255 for each byte.  For such input data, gzip is very well suited.

But each compression algorithm reduces the amount of repetition and redundancy as much as possible, so that a later compression algorithm cannot reduce the data size anymore.  So trying to gzip a PNG or JPG file doesn't help anything.  In fact it will only add some protocol overhead.

So I assume in your case you should switch off the gzip compression again.

It was good to try it out, though, because now you know that this option doesn't speed up anything for you (which is often hard to estimate without trying).

Comment: Hi Alfe, Thanks for taking the time to reply. My files are html files, so not already compressed, and as I stated I observed that my compressed files were 3 times as small as my original files, which is a significant decrease. Despite that, the loading time for my page was the exact same with or without zipping, and I find hard to believe that the zipped version loading time + the time taken to unzip would add up exactly to the original (unzipped) loading time.

Comment: I gave a little more general information than just what made sense in your case.  If your HTML files have been reduced from 30k to 10k then they seem significantly smaller until you notice that the handshake for downloading one takes a second and downloading it takes a microsecond — or a third of a microsecond with compression.  I cannot know for sure in your case but I would suspect that you would notice a really _significant_ increase in load time only for files in the dozens of megabyte range, and I doubt that you HTML files are that large.